# How to show mobile menu on Shopify Site

Tags: css, mobile, shopify, responsive

I have designed a new site using the Timber Framework in Shopify and I am now trying to sort out the responsive side to ensure this works on all devices properly.

The problem I am currently facing is that when the screen is resized to below 768px the desktop menu goes away which is fine but no menu shows up at all and I am not sure why this is. Initially when I added the Timber Framework then this was working and I have looked through the theme.liquid file but can't work why this is happening.

The site itself can be viewed at : http://www.prontaprint247.com

If somebody could please advise as to where I have gone wrong as not sure how to fix this issue.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

My menu code in theme.liquid

```
<div id="NavDrawer" class="drawer drawer--left">
    <div class="drawer__header">
      <div class="drawer__title h3">{{ 'layout.drawers.browse' | t }}</div>
      <div class="drawer__close js-drawer-close">
        <button type="button" class="icon-fallback-text">
          <span class="icon icon-x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="fallback-text">{{ 'layout.drawers.close_menu' | t }}</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- begin mobile-nav -->
    <ul class="mobile-nav">
      <li class="mobile-nav__item mobile-nav__search">
        {% include 'search-bar' %}
      </li>
      {% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
        {% comment %}
          Create a dropdown menu by naming a linklist the same as a link in the parent nav

          More info on dropdowns:
            - http://docs.shopify.com/manual/your-website/navigation/create-drop-down-menu
        {% endcomment %}
        {% assign child_list_handle = link.title | handleize %}
        {% if linklists[child_list_handle].links != blank %}
          <li class="mobile-nav__item{% if link.active %} mobile-nav__item--active{% endif %}" aria-haspopup="true">
            <div class="mobile-nav__has-sublist">
              <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="mobile-nav__link">{{ link.title }}</a>
              <div class="mobile-nav__toggle">
                <button type="button" class="icon-fallback-text mobile-nav__toggle-open">
                  <span class="icon icon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="fallback-text">See More</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="icon-fallback-text mobile-nav__toggle-close">
                  <span class="icon icon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="fallback-text">{{ 'cart.general.close_cart' | t | json }}</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="mobile-nav__sublist">
              {% for childlink in linklists[child_list_handle].links %}
                <li class="mobile-nav__item {% if childlink.active %} mobile-nav__item--active{% endif %}">
                  <a href="{{ childlink.url }}" class="mobile-nav__link">{{ childlink.title | escape }}</a>
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="mobile-nav__item{% if link.active %} mobile-nav__item--active{% endif %}">
            <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="mobile-nav__link">{{ link.title }}</a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      {% comment %}
        If customer accounts are enabled, provide login and create account links
      {% endcomment %}
      {% if shop.customer_accounts_enabled %}
        {% if customer %}
          <li class="mobile-nav__item">
            {% if customer.first_name != blank %}
              {% capture first_name %}{{ customer.first_name }}{% endcapture %}
              <a href="/account">{{ 'layout.customer.logged_in_as_html' | t: first_name: first_name }}</a>
            {% else %}
              <a href="/account">{{ 'layout.customer.account' | t }}</a>
            {% endif %}
          </li>
          <li class="mobile-nav__item">
            {{ 'layout.customer.log_out' | t | customer_logout_link }}
          </li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="mobile-nav__item">
            {{ 'layout.customer.log_in' | t | customer_login_link }}
          </li>
          <li class="mobile-nav__item">
            {{ 'layout.customer.create_account' | t | customer_register_link }}
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
    <!-- //mobile-nav -->
  </div>
```

Comment: By the looks of it, both your desktop menu and the mobile menu are in the div `id= NavDrawer`. When the screen is resized, this NavDrawer gets a `display:none` style attached, thus hiding both menus. It looks like you either need to move your menu out of the `NavDrawer`, or change the code so it'll only hide `Drawer_Header`.

Comment: Tijmen, thanks for having a look at this really appreciate it.

Comment: Tijmen, having looked at my code, your right my mobile menu is being shown within the NavDrawer class (as shown above), but when i compare this to the original theme.liquid file within the Timber Framework, then I notice that the code has remained the same, but one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Hm, in that case my gut says there may be something wrong with the javascript that hides the menu. Did you change anything there?

Comment: To be fair I haven't changed anything, but I do have a carousel slider, a hover feature that use javascript to function and may be this is causing a conflict...